Issues about upgrading JumpServer from v3 to v4
I have been leveraging JumpServer as my personal gateway tool (jump host maybe) for quite some time now. While it's an open-source gem with tremendous utility, the primary support channel has
been only within the Chinese community. Recently,JumpServer v4 has a revamped English user interface and extends technical support in English in discord(you can find it on github).I upgrade my jumpserver immediately and got a strange error.
It seems like a db problem
I just want to upgrade my jumpserver from v3.7.2 to v4.0.0, it seems it switch to pg instead of mysql. Is that a problem?

It seems it has to first upgrade the existing environment to the latest version in the v3.x series (at least to v3.10.11). Otherwise, the upgrade process to v4.0.0 will not be possible.

After reviewing the source code on GitHub, I noticed that the database migration script has a hardcoded value for the administrator's default name. It seems that changing the administrator's name back to "admin" allowed for a successful upgrade.
enter image description here
